# solr tagging & excluding filters for range facets

Tags: solr, filter, facet

I'm creating a uneven range facet and I want to support multiple selection for it. However, facet on the tags/exclusions for filters stop working. 
Following is my price facet ranges
0-20
20-50
50-100
100-*
Initially I am populating above range with using facet query.
Now whenever end user are selecting 0-20 and 20-50,
I am generating the following

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/catalog/select?q=games&facet=true&wt=xml&rows=0&     fq={!tag=salePrice}salePrice:[0 TO 20]&facet.query={!ex=salePrice}[0 to 20]&      fq={!ex=salePrice}salePrice:[20 TO 50]&facet.query={!ex=salePrice}[20 to 50]&       other params.
```

& system is returning zero results.

I am seeing following SOLR JIRA bug closed as fixed.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-3819

However, in case,only one facet.query is in action.
In my example, i am using multiple facet.query with uneven ranges.
Please help.

Comment: fq={!tag=salePrice}salePrice:[0 TO 20]&facet.query={!ex=salePrice}[0 to 20]&      fq={!ex=salePrice}salePrice:[20 TO 50]&facet.query={!ex=salePrice}[20 to 50]&

Comment: Did you get solution?

Comment: BTW, I noticed that both lower and upper bounds are inclusive, which means there is overlap...could be confusing to your users.  You can use `}` instead of `]` to make the upper bound exclusive.

Answer (score 0):

Your query has two `fq` clauses that don't overlap.  That is why you get zero results — nothing to do with the facets or tags themselves.  For multi selection you need to combine them with an "OR".

Instead of

```
...&fq={!tag=salePrice}salePrice:[0 TO 20]&...&fq={!ex=salePrice}salePrice:[20 TO 50]&...
```

you want

```
...&fq={!tag=salePrice}salePrice:[0 TO 20] OR salePrice:[20 TO 50]&...
```

(or combine into a single range)